# virtual pages associated with each running process

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, process

How can I list out all processes that are currently running on my system, and print the virtual pages allocated to it and number of page faults associated with each process?

Comment: I'd say Rajesh' answer below is pretty much what you are looking for. Have a look at it please. If you feel that your question is answered, please to mark it as such. This will make clear that the question is closed and help others with a similar issue. Otherwise a comment on what is missing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: [print virtual pages associated with processes](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/linux-print-virtual-pages-associated-with-processes-4175436101/)

> I don't know about associating page faults to pages or to processes. But the virtual pages of each process are available from
>
> ```
> /proc/pid/smaps
> ```
>
> where you replace `pid` with the pid of each task you want info on.

Comment: Whilst a link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
ps -eo pid,sz,maj_flt,min_flt
```

See ps manual for more information.